# Transpose some columns of an Excel table

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007, microsoft-excel-2013, microsoft-excel-2016

I am not able to achieve going from this format:

[image]

To this format:

[image]

I could transpose manually, but there are hundreds of items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure you have column headers on your source table, then put your cursor anywhere in the table and use Data>Get & Transform Data>From Table/Range.

This will open the Power Query Editor. Select the "Item" column, like this:

[image]

Now use Transform>Any Column>Unpivot Columns>Unpivot Other Columns. This will give you:

[image]

Now right click the Attribute column and use Remove.

Finally, use Home>Close & Load to put the data back into the workbook.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer!